# How to create elementor header for the website that uses guternberg page builder

Tags: wordpress, header, elementor, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using a theme that uses Gutenberg page builder, I am also using Elementor templated in between the pages using shortcode, but now I am creating a header with Elementor, and no any section is visible except Elementor templated.  how can I use the Elementor header with a different page builder? I also have Elementor pro

I tried using a separate plugin for the header footer builder but that also did not work